# How to use the webcam's microphone in Skype?

Tags: sound, webcam, skype, microphone

I'd like to use my camera's microfone to chat within skype.

In my systemwide sound options, I have two entries in the Equipment tab: One Duplex for the Internal SoundCard and one input for the camera. Though, I am unable to get the camera's entry listed on the "Input" tab. Does anyone know how should I proceed in order to use my camera's microphone?

Thanks,
Pedro

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My problem was that the webcam wasn't listed in the input tab. I was able to fix this by pluging the camera in and rebooting with it connected to the computer.

Answer (score 2):

First check the input tab, if your webcam mic is there, select the radio button beside it.
If it isn't listed. Go into the hardware tab. Select the webcam input and change the Profile below. Then go into the input tab and select the radio button.

If it is selected in the input tab, it should work in Skype.

Answer (score 2):

It is not needed to install **alsamixer**. The problem is, that Skype doesn't know where to listen and there is no option how to say in Skype environment directly. Install **PulseAudio Volume Control** from **Ubuntu Software Center** or via **Synaptic**.

Start Skype and choose **Options** from blue **S** down. Select **Sound Services**. Check if both three options (Microphone, Speakers, Ringing) has setted PulseAudio Server (local).
Uncheck **Allow Skype to automatically...** to prevent too silent sound.

Click button **Open PulseAudio Volume Control**, it should be visible down (if not, open it clasically from menu).

[image: Skype Sound Services]

In opened **PulseAudio Volume Control** application click tab **Input devices** and check, if microphone is functioning (it is visible on the horizontal scale).

Than click tab **Recording**. The page should be empty (no another device is recording).
In Skype call **Echo/Sound test service**, or call somebody, who is able to endure on line. This is only that way, how to set up microphone! During the session in **Volume Control** is visible what is recording. Push button in upper right corner and choose your web camera microphone input from list.

[image]

In next session Skype should remember those settings, so it is not needed to do this setting always. I suppose, that it is stored in `~/.Skype` directory for further session.
Tested on Ubuntu x86-64 13.10, 14.04, 15.04, 15.10, 16.04 Skype 4.2.0.11, 4.3.0.37.

Comment: You are rocks!!!

Answer (score 1):

The problem is with Skype - for some reason the microphone stops working. Even though the mic was working alright with other software, it wasn't with Skype.  I just entered:

```
sudo apt-get install skype
```

and things got back to normal.

Answer (score 0):

I solve that issue on my **natty** *installing alsamixer packages and deleted full Pulseaudio package. Of course, the Banshee connection on the top bar will disappear, but for me was the only way to solve it. Now, i use alsamixer controllers on the left unity bar to control volume.
Don't forget to change de soundboard on skype options (choose this option if this is your case: **"HDA ATI SB ALC888 Analog Default Audio Device"**)

and in the terminal (CTRL+ALT+T) type:
alsamixer

then you'll have the power to control all of the sound of your machine and perhaps you should take care about disable **"mic boost**" and enable **"Capture"**.

I hope i helped you.

Jorge